# Code will not filter data in SQL

Tags: php, mysql

This is my issue I can pull all the data to a webpage but when I try the filter the data by first or last name I get this err:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'samuel' OR last_name = 'samuel'' at line 1

```
        include "link.php";

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM persons";

//filter I think my problem is in here might be wrong //
        if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

        $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);


       $sql .= "WHERE first_name = '{$search_term}'";

        $sql .= "OR last_name = '{$search_term}'";

        }


       $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>

//Form//
        &nbsp
          <p>
          </p>
      <form name="search_form" method="POST" action="search_data.php">

         Search: <input type="text" name="search_box" value=""/>
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search the table...". >
       </form>
    <p>
</p>

<table width="70%" border="2" cellpadding="1" cellspace="1">

<tr>
    <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Date____Time</strong></td>
    <td><strong>First Name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Middle Name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Last Name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Email Address</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Phone Number</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Date_of_Birth</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Home______Address</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Monthly Salary</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Loan Amount</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Loan Term</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Loan Due Date</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Employer_Name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Employer______Address</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Employer Phone Number</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Reference First Name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Reference Last Name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Reference Phone Number</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Reference_____Address</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Payment Made</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Payment Made</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Balance</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
<tr>

   <td><?php echo $row['persons_ID'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['date'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['first_name'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['middle_name'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['last_name'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['email_address'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['phone_number'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['date_of_birth'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['home_address'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['monthly_salary'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['loan_amount'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['loan_term'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['loan_due_date'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['employer_name'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['employer_address'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['employer_phone_number'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['reference_first_name'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['reference_last_name'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['reference_phone_number'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['reference_address'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['payment_made'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['payment_made'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['balance'];?></td>
```

Comment: put space `$sql .= " OR last_name`

Comment: In situations like this, it can be helpful to echo out the query ($sql) and inspect it in its entirety, then run that directly against the db if you can. In this case, it looks to be spacing. There is no space between persons and WHERE.

Comment: Can please you give me an Example.

Comment: got it thanks guys... wow the little things